# Entropy of a single variable given mutual probability distribution of two variables

Tags: statistics, information-theory, entropy

Let's say that we have a random variable $(X,Y)$ that can take in two four values. The respective probabilities are:
$p(x,y) = Pr(X=x \land Y=y)$

$$p(0,0) = \frac 1 4$$
$$p(0,1) = \frac 3 8 $$
$$p(1,0) = \frac 1 8$$
$$p(1,1) = \frac 1 4 $$

Now, it is very easy to calculate the entropy $H(X,Y)$ straight from the definition.

However, let's say that I need to calculate $H(X)$. How do I attempt to do that? Will:
$$H(X) = Pr(Y=0)H(X|Y=0) + Pr(Y=1)H(X|Y=1)$$

work?

Comment: What about writing the distribution of $X$ and from there calculate $H(X)$?

Comment: There is no such “law of total entropy.”  Imagine if there were we would get for any Bernoulli variable $Z$: $$ H(Z)=H(Z|Z=0)P[Z=0]+H(Z|Z=1)P[Z=1]=0+0=0$$